# Two model. Selection list. Not unique

Tags: python, django

I have two models. I want that to field first model was the selection list of the field of the second model. But field of secondary model is not unique.

Think, need to redifine field in admin form

Help me to realize this, plese. I am study django.

country models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Country(models.Model):
    class Meta():
        db_table = 'country'

    country_region = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    country_city = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    country_district = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True, null=True)
```

client models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from client.models import Client

# Create your models here.
class Client(models.Model):
    class Meta():
        db_table = 'client'

    client_name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    client_region = models.CharField(max_length=300) #maybe ForeignKey
```

I want select list (choices) in client_region (from country region) in admin

I'm trying in admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from country.models import Country
from client.models import Client

class ClientAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            new_choices = Country.objects.values('country_region').distinct()
            super(ClientAdmin.form, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
            self.field['client_region'].choices = new_choices

# Register your models here.
admin.site.register(Client, ClientAdmin)
```

And I try this code, but it is not work

admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from timetable.models import Client
from house.models import Country
from django.forms import ModelChoiceField, ModelForm, forms

class ClientForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Client

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ClientForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.field['client_region'] = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Country.objects.values['county_region'])

class ClientAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['client_region']
    form = ClientForm

# Register your models here.
admin.site.register(Client, ClientAdmin)
```

Answer (score 0):

For what you want to do (if I understand, get the list of Clients by region), the way I'd go would be to create a third model "Region", and link Client and Country to this model with a ForeignKey.

I'm not sure to understand very well your problem though, can you try to reformulate it?

Comment: Yes, this is simple and good way. But I want make choices-list from field country_region.

Comment: Maybe try to see this threat : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12626171/django-admin-choice-field