# Unknown field(s) (client_value, client_name) specified for Client. Check fields/fieldsets/exclude attributes of class ClientDataAdmin

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I have a model that I want to add to my admin pages.

The model class is.

```
class Client(models.Model):
    FBUSER = "FBU"
    GOOGLEUSER = "GU"
    FBACCESSCODE = "FBAC"
    GOOGLESECRET = "GS"
    MISC = "MISC"
    CLIENT_KEY_CHOICES = [
        (FBUSER, "Facebook User ID"),
        (FBACCESSCODE, "Facebook Access Code"),
        (GOOGLEUSER, "Google User"),
        (GOOGLESECRET, "Google Secret"),
        (MISC, "Misc"),
    ]
    client_key = models.CharField(
        max_length=4,
        choices=CLIENT_KEY_CHOICES,
        default=FBUSER,
    )

    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key = True),
    client_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null = True),
    client_value = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null = True),
```

and my admin.py is

```
class ClientDataAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fieldsets = [
        (None,               {'fields': ['client_key', 'client_name', 'client_value' ]}),
    ]
    
    list_display = ('client_name', 'client_key', 'client_value')
    search_fields = ['client_name']
```

I have looked at several similar error explanations and fixes but none fit, this case.

I have other models and admin scripts that work fine, but I cannot find anything wrong here.

The admin page shows the add link but I get the following error when I hit it...

```
Unknown field(s) (client_value, client_name) specified for Client. Check fields/fieldsets/exclude attributes of class ClientDataAdmin.
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/admin/kdconnector/client/add/
Django Version: 4.1.7
Exception Type: FieldError
Exception Value:    
Unknown field(s) (client_value, client_name) specified for Client. Check fields/fieldsets/exclude attributes of class ClientDataAdmin.
```

I suspect it comes from the choices for the client_key but I cannot find the solution. I took the documentation example and adapted it to the client_key in the model. So I tried the following with changes to model and admin.

models.py

```
class Client(models.Model):
id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key = True),

CHOICES = (
    ('FBU', 'Facebook User'),
    ('GGU', 'Google User'),
    ('FBAC', 'Facebook Access'),
    ('GGS', 'Google Secret'),
    ('MISC', 'Misc'),
)

client_key = models.CharField(max_length=25, null=False, choices=CHOICES)

client_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null = True),
client_value = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null = True),
```

admin.py

```
    @admin.register(Client)
class ClientAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('client_key', 'client_name', 'client_value')
```

The good news is the error went away, but now in the admin pages for client, 'Add Client' gives only the client_key pull down but not the client_name or client_value fields.

The Client list looks like this after adding.

[image]

Comment: I found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12626171/django-admin-choice-field and tried that answer but to no avail.  I added a forms.ModelForm class and moved the choices into that and changed the ClientDataAdmin class to add the form.  No change to the error.

Answer (score 0):

Ok darned commas.  ;-)

The problem was in the model where I had commas after the last two fields.

```
client_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null = True),
client_value = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null = True),
```

When I removed the commas

```
client_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null = True)
client_value = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null = True)
```

It all started working properly.